# instantiate navigationservice class

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I was working on a WPF project today that had a main nav window and then 4 pages that were loaded within this main window (using NavigationService.Nagivate...).. Within the XAML this created a lot of duplicate code so I wanted to refactor the menu into a user control that I could then bind to each page. I tried to create a class to handle the navigation and loading of each page but I discovered that NavigationServices is a sealed class and cannot be instantiated.

Would anyone please provide a suggestion/solution on how to create a usercontrol with a menu item that will allow the ability to navigate to new pages within the project. I have been able to do this within pages and the direct code behind but I have not had any luck trying to separate the two. If this is too vague please let me know and I will provide more deails with code samples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a NavigationService dependency property on your user control.  Then, when you instantiate your control, bind this property to the NavigationService of the container where the navigation should occur.  For example, a page might display the user control like this:

```
<local:NavBox NavigationService="{Binding NavigationService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type NavigationWindow}}}" />
```

Now when your UserControl calls Navigate on its NavigationService, that will effectively call Navigate on the containing NavigationWindow's NavigationService.  (This can be modified in the obvious way to support Frame or Page instead of NavigationWindow.)

Comment: itowlson, I think I am missing something because when I create the method within uc to handle the Navigation property I get an exception that the method cannot contain an annonymous parameter. Where ( I think) I am getting stuck is how can to instantiate NavigationService class so that within my class I can allow each menu item to navigate to a new page.  How does a DP factor into this solution? Thank you

Comment: You can't instantiate a new NavigationService.  What you need to do is get a NavigationService from somebody who already has one, and use that.  That is where the binding comes in: it gets you a reference to the container's NavigationService, on which you can call Navigate.  The DP comes in because only DPs can be binding targets.  Regarding 'method cannot contain an anonymous parameter,' could you post your code and the exception message?

Comment: I posted a sample solution to https://www.onlinefilefolder.com/4ssuiush4HAlac If it's not too much trouble could you look at this and let me know where I should set and register the DP's would they be in the user control itself? Also I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by getting the Service from somebody else who already has it? I tried to do that creating a static class as you wills see in the solution unless I missunderstand the statement. Thanks again for any and all suggestions. I've marked you as correct as I think it puts me on the right track i just need to read up some more. -cheers

Comment: By 'getting the service from someone else' I mean you have a Page or NavigationWindow that already has a NavigationService.  So you can use theirs instead of trying to create one of your own.  Re code sample:  You would declare the NavigationService DP in uc_menu.xaml.cs, and change your Click handler to `this.NavigationService.Navigate(...)`.  Then in Page1.xaml you would add the binding to the `local:uc_menu` element.